# Download data even when the application is terminated

Tags: ios, swift, api, background

Is this possible to download data when the application is terminated? I want to download data at a particular time to get new updates in my API. And if data download in the background after that if user run application again, the user has no need to wait for download new data.

Answer (score 0):

If the application [server] that is serving the content has been terminated the answer is no. (There is nothing to continue writing data out to the buffer/stream)

You will need to provide more details regarding your applications concerns to determine if there is some sort of caching layer that *could* be implemented which would allow your downloads to be resumable in some cases.

Comment: Server side is not terminated, they will update the file at a particular time. And I want to download updated files even when the application terminated. I try to use Background fetch but this only works when the application is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't continue download when your app get terminated by user! Your app must require to remains in background state!!! Because if user force close app that means, he doesn't want to run it anymore. If your app is suspended by system then it can be wake up but not if it's terminated by user!

Comment: In my case, if the user terminates the app. As you mentioned it is not possible in this case. Can you provide me with any Apple site link, where it is mentioned that it is not possible to download data when the app is terminated?

Comment: link is mentioned in vivekDas answer.

Comment: "Note: If the user terminates the app by force-quiting from the app switcher, the system will cancel all of the session’s background transfers, and won’t attempt to relaunch the app." Source : https://www.raywenderlich.com/567-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Ok, I didn't saw that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See there are two types of termination, one if user do from app switcher and another one is if iOS do. If user terminates its not possible to do any thing in background. But in case of iOS terminates your app it can continue download or background task. Check about `NSURLsession` background download for more info.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background?language=objc

https://www.raywenderlich.com/567-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: In my case, if the user terminates the app. As you mentioned it is not possible in this case. Can you provide me with any Apple site link, where it is mentioned that it is not possible to download data when the app is terminated?

Comment: You can check the links I listed in my ans. also these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379493/will-download-resume-after-closing-my-app-in-background-mode, https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80743

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with other answer. You can't continue download when your app get terminated by user!
But I'm not agree with you about Background app refresh.

#### Background app refresh

Here is [Apple's definition :](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202070)

> After you switch to a different app, some apps run for a short period of time before they're set to a suspended state. Apps that are in a suspended state aren’t actively in use, open, or taking up system resources. With Background App Refresh, suspended apps can check for updates and new content.

And here some parts from another [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW56)

> Apps that need to check for new content periodically can ask the system to wake them up so that they can initiate a fetch operation for that content.
> ...
> Enabling this mode is not a guarantee that the system will give your app any time to perform background fetches.

iOS try to predict when user will launch app on next time. iOS launches the app in background to update content right before the momnent when user launch the app.

#### Another approach to update content is use the Push Notifications

[Here is from Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW57)

> If your server sends push notifications to a user’s device when new content is available for your app, you can ask the system to run your app in the background so that it can begin downloading the new content right away.

Notification’s payload must include the `content-available` key with its value set to 1. This key lets iOS to know that the notification is silent.
[Pushing Updates to Your App Silently.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_updates_to_your_app_silently)